# Purpose of #define-ing symbol as itself in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm looking at some provided C headers for a microprocessor, and they contain code like:

```
#define TMR2 TMR2
extern volatile unsigned int   TMR2 __attribute__((section("sfrs")));
```

What is the purpose of this `#define`?

Comment: Wouldn't `#undef` be a better way to acheive that?

Comment: See also [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Undefining-and-Redefining-Macros.html): "If a macro is redefined with a definition that is not effectively the same as the old one, **the preprocessor issues a warning** [emphasis mine] and changes the macro to use the new definition."

Comment: Having seen the duplicate, in this case it's being used to allow feature-detection of the microprocessor - different variants have different registers